# Does the scala ! subprocess command waits for the subprocess to finish?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, I have the following kind of code running in each map tasks on Spark.

```
@volatile var res = (someProgram + fileName) !
var cmdRes = ("rm " + fileName) !;
```

The filenames for each map tasks are unique. The basic idea is that once the first command finishes, the second command deletes the file. However, I notice that the program sometimes complain that the file does not exist. It seems that the subprocess call is not synchronous, that is, it does not wait for the subprocess to complete. Is that correct. And if it indeed the case, how can we correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@!%28log:scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger%29:Int), the `!` method blocks until exit.  The docs say that it:

> Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, and returns the exit code.

It's possible that you should be checking the exit code to interpret the result and to deal with exceptional cases.

When creating process commands by concatenation, you are often better off using the `Seq` extensions (as opposed to the `String` ones) to create a `ProcessBuilder`.  The [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) even include this helper, which might help you:

```
// This uses ! to get the exit code
def fileExists(name: String) = Seq("test", "-f", name).! == 0
```

Comment: Is there any difference between x.! and x!

Comment: No difference, really.  Under most circumstances, it would be considered merely a stylistic distinction.  The bang `!` is just a method, and you can invoke a method with either a space or dot.  You can read more about method invocation and recommended style in Scala [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) or [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-methods-dots-spaces-single-one-parameter)